# pyautogui and Xlib, combined with multiprocessing, throws RuntimeError: "Expected reply for request 9, but got 15. Can't happen"

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pyautogui

I have a rather odd problem with my program. The idea is simple enough: using Open-cv to match multiple templates on the screen from Image.grab(). It does not matter which of the two templates match first; I've been able to kill the running multiprocess function if one of the other functions completes.

Each template matching function will move to the center of the template image on the screen, verifying that it has indeed found the template on the screen, regardless of where it is.

Both functions use Pyautogui to make the mouse move at the very end of both functions.

This is where the problem starts: After finding the template on the screen, pyautogui is called to move the mouse to the center of the template, but calling another function either inside or outside of the function that uses pyautogui raises a runtime error:

```
File "/home/killingball/Downloads/Image_resizing_tests.py", line 211, in <module>
  test1()
File "/home/killingball/Downloads/Image_resizing_tests.py", line 85, in test1
  pyautogui.moveTo(800,800)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 597, in wrapper
  failSafeCheck()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 1721, in failSafeCheck
  if FAILSAFE and tuple(position()) in FAILSAFE_POINTS:
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 765, in position
  posx, posy = platformModule._position()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 32, in _position
  coord = _display.screen().root.query_pointer()._data
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/xobject/drawable.py", line 561, in query_pointer
  return request.QueryPointer(display = self.display,
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/rq.py", line 1481, in __init__
  self.reply()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/rq.py", line 1493, in reply
  self._display.send_and_recv(request = self._serial)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 556, in send_and_recv
  gotreq = self.parse_response(request)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 643, in parse_response
  gotreq = self.parse_request_response(request) or gotreq
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 726, in parse_request_response
  raise RuntimeError("Expected reply for request %s, but got %s. Can't happen!"
RuntimeError: Expected reply for request 9, but got 15. Can't happen!
```

I don't have a clue as to what the heck the error means and could really use some help making sense of the error or whatever I might be doing wrong within the code.

```
def test1():
    print('sleeping for 5 sec....')
    pyautogui.moveTo(800,800)
    time.sleep(5)
    print('done sleeping 1')
    #star_threads()
 
def test2():
    print('sleeping for 1 sec....')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('done sleeping 2')
    exit()
 
def something(event):
    while True:
        image_gray = np.array(cv.cvtColor(cv.imread('/run/media/marcos/8d82f6aa-2fc2-4eb7-ba62-e714d909f394/Old files/PycharmProjects/REDLIGHT_automation/Video_player_end.png'), cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY))
        # a = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 2560, 1440)))
        b = cv.cvtColor(np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 2560, 1440))), cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        h1, w1, = image_gray.shape[::-1]
        REGION = 796, 574, 1756, 973
        x, y, w, h = REGION
        result = cv.matchTemplate(
            image=b,
            templ=image_gray,
            method=cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
        # print('thread 1', max_val, )
        # cv.imshow('b', b)
        #print(f'thread one max value:{max_val}')
        while not event:
 
            break
        print(max_val)
        if max_val >= 0.95:# this was 0.79
            x1, y2 = (h1 / 2) + max_loc[0], (w1 / 2) + max_loc[1]
            pyautogui.moveTo(x=x1, y=y2)
            del result, min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc
            event.set()
            os.kill(t2, __signal=(exit()))
 
            break
        event.set()
 
def something2(event):
    # checker1=z
    # print(processes[0])
 
    while True:
        image_gray = np.array(cv.cvtColor(cv.imread("/home/marcos/Pictures/reject_window.png"), cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY))
        # a = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 2560, 1440)))
        b = cv.cvtColor(np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 2560, 1440))), cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        h1, w1, = image_gray.shape[::-1]
        REGION = 796, 574, 1756, 973
        x, y, w, h = REGION
        result = cv.matchTemplate(
            image=b,
            templ=image_gray,
            method=cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
        # print('thread 2',max_val,)
        # del result
   
        #print(f'thread two max value:{max_val}')
   
        _FINISH = False
        print(max_val)
        if max_val >= 0.98:
     
            #print('thread 2 found found the reject window')
            x1, y2 = (h1 / 2) + max_loc[0], (w1 / 2) + max_loc[1]
   
            pyautogui.moveTo(x=x1, y=y2)
            del result, min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc
            #return var
            #test2()
            event.set()
            #t1.kill()
            t1.kill()
            os.kill(t1,exit())
            #exit()
 
            break
        if max_val<=0.97:
            continue
        break
 
 
            # gc.collect()
 
if __name__=="__main__":
 
    while True:
 
        event = Event()
        t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=something, daemon=True, args=(event,))
        t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=something2, daemon=True, args=(event,))
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        # t2.join()
        # print(t1.is_alive())
        # print(t2.is_alive())
        if t1.is_alive:
            # print('t1 is alive')
            t1.join()
            # t2.join()
            t1.close()
            # t1.terminate()
            # t2.terminate()
            break
 
        if t2.is_alive:
            # print(t2.is_alive())
            print('t2 is alive')
            t2.join()
            # t2.terminate()
            t2.close()
            # t1.terminate()
            break
        break
        # t1.join()
        # t1.terminate()
 
    # print(f'thread two status:{t2.is_alive()}')
    # print(f'thread one status:{t1.is_alive()}')
 
    if t2.is_alive() == False:
        print('thread TWO found it,thread one was still running')
        #t1.close()
        test1()
    if t2.is_alive() == True:
        print('Thread ONE found it, thread two was still running')
        # print(t2.is_alive())
 
        #t2.kill()
        # test2()
```

Comment: Can you try to debug by isolating and removing parts of the code? For example instead of template matching you could randomly decide to call the function.

Comment: removing the opencv template matching is the main goal of both function something() and something2(), so that's a bit of a no dice on that part. Or do you believe that template matching is what causes the error?

Comment: Do you know where exactly the error is occurring? If not, put print statements liberally in the code to find out where. Also check each image (shape and type) to be sure you are getting the correct results and that your paths are correct.

Comment: The stack trace says that you are connecting to an X server, right? Can you give any details on your environment that describe what you are actually doing? Which size does the client window have, does this fit to your hard coded 800, 800 position etc. ?

Comment: @Micka it turns out calling test1() from the ``if __name__=="__main__" ``block is what raises the error.... calling test1() from either function does not result in any error.

Comment: I've reformatted the traceback. this is a ton of code. please review [mre]. learn how to debug programs with this article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ -- I've removed the opencv tag. the error clearly relates to pyautogui and something platform-specific. perhaps pyautogui isn't safe to use with multiprocessing? remove all the multiprocessing. you aren't ready for it. do your matchTemplate calls in sequence. you gain _nothing_ from multiprocessing. OpenCV already does it where possible.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You are right, i'm not ready to fully deploy something like multiprocessing. Thank you for the links; I will give them a read later this evening. And yes, removing the multiprocessing and having the code happen in sequence works just fine. The code runs just fine if I call my test1(), but it feels hacky, and I still find myself curious if I can find a little more speed in executing my personal projects. I'm not giving up just yet for now, but I'm going over the python docs to better understand multiprocessing since it feels like something I might want to know later on.